# Invocar archivo .tpl desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, smarty

buenas tardes. Tengo la siguiente duda, ¿puedo invocar y usar desde Javascript un archivo .tpl de Smarty? Lo quiero hacer para poder utilizar una ventana modal. Desde ya, muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent A mí no me parece que a esta pregunta le falte nada de código. No obstante, la recomendaciones de consultar esos apartados son muy adecuadas, Ruben, haz caso.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La respuesta es muy sencilla: **NO**. Al menos, no directamente.

Los tpl de Smarty se procesan del lado del servidor.
Javascript se ejecuta en el cliente (tu navegador).

No obstante, puedes desde Javascript hacer una llamada por Ajax y recibir el contenido del tpl, ya procesado.

Quizá lo que quieres hacer es un modal con un formulario para editar algún registro, de forma que quieres que cuando pulses sobre determinado elemento (de una lista quizá) entonces aparezca el modal con el formulario, y con los datos de ese elemento cargados. En este caso, puedes pintar el modal, incluyendo el formulario, en la plantilla tpl que ya estás manejando (la que muestra la lista), y lo que harías es, al pinchar para editar un elemento, realizar una llamada Ajax para obtener sus datos, pasarlos mediante Javascript al formulario, y mostrar el modal (con el formulario).

Échale imaginación. Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.